# Using $scope values in creation of other scope values in an angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have latitude and longitude data pass to me from the server and is saved in as $scope.Adress, I need to make a map object using those values like you see below. However this doesn't work and what I need answered is how do I format this so it will work.

```
 $scope.map = {
       center: {
          latitude: $scope.Address.Latitude,
          longitude: $scope.Address.Longitude
       },
       markers: [{
          latitude: $scope.Address.Latitude,
          longitude: $scope.Address.Longitude
       }],
        zoom: 15
 };
```

Comment: I see no reason why this wouldn't work. What error are you getting? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Unless it's a typo. You say you save the location data in $scope.Adress, but your code uses $scope.Address.

Comment: So if I am using it correctly that is the answer, I guess I need to look for other stuff like typos. John put that up as the answer and I will give it to you

Comment: Or provide more information. For example, have you tried inspecting $scope.Address to make sure it has values? Or if you could prepare a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might just be a typo. You say you save the location data in $scope.Adress, but your code uses $scope.Address.